# How to compare one column with many columns (1200 columns) to find identical names?

Tags: linux, text-processing

There are about a text file with 1200 columns with different length.Please kindly note that, in this file, the header name of columns, except for the first column (S1 column) is identical with the contents within the first column (A, B, C, D, E, F). something like below:

```
S1  A   B   C   D   E   F
A   A   I   C   D   E   F
B   B   B   K       D   L
C   F   E           A   E
D   H               C   N
E                       
F
```

I would like to compare the first column (S1) with the rest of columns and find identical items between the first column and column 2, between the first column and column 3, and so on. Then, print the identical items in the new column (here, column O). The desired output is like below:

```
S1  A   B   C   D   E   F   O
A   A   I   C   D   E   F   A,B,F
B   B   B   K       D   L   B,E
C   F   E           A   E   C
D   H               C   N   D
E                           E,D,A,C
F                           F,E
```

Here, the O column is the desired output column, which the identical names between S1 column and the second column (column A) is printed in the front of A in the column S1; similarly, the identical names between S1 column and the third column (column B) is printed in the front of B in the column S1, and so on.

Comment: Is there some other way to describe the construction of the `O` column? I don't understand why the `B` is there on the 2nd line, or `E` on the 3rd, or _any_ of the other entries of that column on the remaining lines.

Comment: Shouldn't the first output not be `A,B,F` instead of `A,B`? @Kusalananda, remove the first row (header), take 2nd column `A,B,F,H` and find all matching letters in first column -> `A,B,F`, take 3rd column `I,B,E` + search in 1st column -> `B,E`, ...

Comment: Having the data in rows rather than columns would have made the matching bit easier.

Comment: Thanks all. That's right Freedy, it is actually A, B, F, the identical items between the first column and the second column. I have more than 1000 columns, comparing one-by-one is really time-consuming. Kusalananda, sorry if it's not clear. A,B,F is on the 2nd line becuase they are identical between the first column (S1) and second column (A). E and also B on the 3rd becuase they are identical between the first column (S1) and third column (B), and so on.

Comment: In the row `C   F   E         A   E   C` how can you tell that the 3rd and 4th columns are empty? Are the contents of each column exactly one character? Or are there exactly three blanks between each column and a blank column is one blank character?

Comment: Please define what is a column

Comment: Here, the input is actually the output of another analysis, which I would like just to compare the first column (S1) with other columns and print the identical values in the column O as I showed in the post. The content of each column is 8 characters. No, there are not eactly three blank between columns, the blank randomly located.

Comment: Your question says that columns have a different length, now you say that each column is 8 characters. Please edit the question to give a definition of what is a column.
Usually table files either have a fixed delimiter between columns (like csv) or a fixed column width. If neither is true, it may be obvious to a human reader to understand what is supposed to be a column, but almost impossible to express as an algorithm to implement.
Is there a chance to change the output of the other tool?

Comment: The columns having differnt "length" actually refers to their column height, I think. This is clear from the condensed diagram.